# %PARSER_ERROR while turning up the server

Tags: parsing, gradle, swagger, swagger-2.0, inflector

I have added 2 gradle dependencies for parsing the yaml contents and generate a json out of it but I am getting these kind of logs when I am trying to turn up my server.

```
%PARSER_ERROR[cyan] %PARSER_ERROR[gray] %PARSER_ERROR[highlight] %PARSER_ERROR[magenta] - Kafka version: 2.3.0
%PARSER_ERROR[cyan] %PARSER_ERROR[gray] %PARSER_ERROR[highlight] %PARSER_ERROR[magenta] - Kafka commitId: fc1aaa116b661c8a
%PARSER_ERROR[cyan] %PARSER_ERROR[gray] %PARSER_ERROR[highlight] %PARSER_ERROR[magenta] - Kafka startTimeMs: 1604911935830
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Gradle dependency excluding the 'ch.qos.logback' group 'logback-core' module solved the issue.